# navigate and redirect not redirecting to path in react router

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, react-router

I have a logistics tab, where if the `logisticData` value is null, I will redirect the page to `"/logistic"` from `":logisticId/edit"`

However, when I do this code, it does not redirect the code

```
function EditLogistic() {
  const { state } = useLocation();
  const logisticData = state;

  console.log(logisticData)

  const navigate = useNavigate();

  if (!logisticData) {
    console.log("empty")
    navigate('/logistic')
    redirect('/logistic')
  }
}
```

I am wondering if I am doing anything wrong, or if there is any way I can achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `redirect` utility function is only valid in the loader and action functions of a Data router, not in a React component.

You can either issue an ***imperative*** navigation action via the `navigate` function from a `useEffect` hook:

```
import { useLocation, useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom';

function EditLogistic() {
  const { state } = useLocation();
  const logisticData = state;

  const navigate = useNavigate();

  useEffect(() => {
    if (!logisticData) {
      navigate("/logistic", { replace: true });
    }
  }, [logisticData, navigate]);

  ...
}
```

Or you can issue a ***declarative*** navigation action via the `Navigate` component:

```
import { Navigate, useLocation } from 'react-router-dom';

function EditLogistic() {
  const { state } = useLocation();
  const logisticData = state;

  if (!logisticData) {
    return <Navigate to="/logistic" replace />;
  }

  ...
}
```

Comment: thanks for giving both solutions,
I tried both imperative and declarative but only the declarative one worked. Not sure why but yea just for people who are reading to note.

Comment: actually regarding my comment on top  I think I understood why haha, because for useEffect() to work the render wil have to happen, but I run into Cannot read properties of null before the useEffect() properly runs. Again, thank you so much for the Imperative solution!!

Comment: @tanshiyu Is there something the `EditLogistic` component tries to render from the `logisticData` value that causes an error? The `useEffect` hook runs *after* the component has rendered once.

Comment: @tanshiyu Ah yeah, then for the imperative solution you'll want to still apply some conditional rendering of the returned UI so the code isn't attempting null/undefined accesses.

Comment: Yeap, will follow this advice and do that haha, again thank u so much for helping me out on this task!!